# не получается переключится на виртуальный хост xampp windows 8.1,то выдает access forbidden,то object not found

Tags: xampp, virtual-hosts

Кое-как создал виртуальный хост *XAMPP*, когда вхожу пишет Access forbidden.

Файл `hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 news.local
127.0.0.1 www.news.local
```

Файл `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@news.local
    DocumentRoot "C:\my_projects\news.local\www"
    ServerName news.local
    ServerAlias www.news.local
    ErrorLog "C:\my_projects\news.local\logs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\my_projects\news.local\logs\access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:\my_projects\news.local\www">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, Вы пользуетесь версией *XAMPP*, в которой присутствует *Apache* версии 2.4. По умолчанию он использует другие команды для распределения доступа. Чтобы доступ работал, замените строки

```
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

на

```
Require all granted
```

Также можно просто перенести каталог с сайтом внутрь каталога `xampp/htdocs`, к которому доступ не блокируется.

---

P.S. Что интересно, команды "старого стиля" должны работать, поскольку в главном конфигурационном файле `httpd.conf` модуль совместимости включен:

```
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
```

Но почему-то не работают...

Comment: спасибо за ответ. во время экспериментов повредил какой-то файл..поэтому переустановил xampp .все заработало)